# invoke method of ui

Tags: visual-studio

```
if (b->InvokeRequired) {
    FuncDelegat^ as = gcnew FuncDelegat(funct1);
    b->Invoke(as,nullptr);
    return;
}
```

Why that code may not the call function funct1

Comment: because call funct1 not call the

Answer (score 1):

funct1 is not called if InvokeRequired returns false. Correct way:

```
    if (b->InvokeRequired) 
    {
        FuncDelegat^ as = gcnew FuncDelegat(funct1);
        b->Invoke(as,nullptr);
    }
    else
    {
        b->funct1(nullptr);
    }
    return;
```

Comment: I added it to the code, but still a function call during a flag does not occur.

Comment: Please provide more information: what is b, delegate type, funct1 definition etc.

Comment: b it is a Form class. i create new thread which must work with Form.  For this i have a function funct1. The delegate FuncDelegat:
delegate void FuncDelegat();